# AssemblyName in Visual Studio error when i publish it

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010

i have a problem to change the name of the application in Visual Studio 2010 ,i explain better my trouble;
last year i develop a project and i called it "Project2011_2012"(it was the original name of the Assembly Name of the project in Visual Studio) and now i develop ,with the copy of the same project, the version 2012_2013 so when when i want publish this version i change just the name in the Option 'Assembly Information' in Visual Studio so after publish the file .exe i run it but after running it there is an error that say there is already a version in the my computer that get the same name (it is the older version of the project 2011_2012) but i can not delete it because in my office they need it to work then do you have any idea how i can publish the both projects with the different name in Assembly Name without error?

Thansk so much for your attention.

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

Did you changed the GUID in AssemblyInfo? Are you publishing it by creating a setup file or just by using the Publish from VS itself? If you do this by creating a setup file, then you need to change Product code and Upgrade Code of the Setup project properties.

Comment: ,hi i am publishing  from VS and now i will try your suggestion and i will let you know the result...Thanks TimVK

Answer (score 1):

You could try updating the Assembly version to for example 2.0.0.0 instead of only the name. You can achieve this in the 'Application' tabpage of your project properties, and then click on the 'Assembly Information ...' button.

Comment: Won't the current application be overwritten if you change the version?

Comment: it is the error now "An error occurred while signing: Key not valid for use in specified state" ... now i check out what mean this error

Comment: guys i followed your advices but not luck i cannot install it succesfully ;(